# PHP code in HTML without a file extension

Tags: php, html, linux, apache, movabletype

I currently have a [Movable Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movable_Type) blog where the pages do not have any file extensions...so example.com/entries/this-is-my-entry

I added `DefaultType text/html`, so Apache knows if there isn't any extension on the end of the file to display as HTML. That works great.

Now the problem is I have PHP code in the HTML. The page won't render the PHP code if there is no extension. However, when I publish the entries with a .html extension....the PHP code works perfectly.

I have `AddHandler php5-script .html` to tell Apache to display PHP in the HTML files. I'm guessing, if there isn't any file extension, it doesn't know to render the PHP code, because it is expecting files with a .html extension...is there a way to say any file that doesn't have an extension can use PHP?

Comment: You should _always_ add an extension to a file. Use `mod_rewrite` if you want URLs with the extension omitted.

Comment: @KingCrunch Why is it bad to have files without an extension?  What is the downside?  According to the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI): `What to leave out - File name extension. This is a very common one. "cgi", even ".html" is something which will change. You may not be using HTML for that page in 20 years time, but you might want today's links to it to still be valid. The canonical way of making links to the W3C site doesn't use the extension.` (Granted, they could still be talking about using rewrites but keeping the extension on the actual file's name).

Comment: @chown I am talking about (physical) files and not, what appears in the browsers addess bar.

Answer (score 4):

I'm doing the same implementation for my personal MT blog, with the entries having no file extension. (The theory being that I could switch to other techniques in the future without being hampered by extensions like .html, .php, etc.)

You can accomplish this by setting your default type to be PHP:

`DefaultType application/x-httpd-php`

All PHP files are interpreted at first as HTML, so this works even for files with no PHP in them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try using <FileMatch> directive? Something like

```
<FilesMatch "^[^\.]$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: This would only match files with a name consisting of 1 single character (if that character is not a `.`).  Add a `+` to match file names of variable length without a period, like this: `<FilesMatch "^[^\.]+$">`

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing directly corresponding to `DefaultType` for `AddHandler`, but you can hack around it in a fairly ugly way:

```
<FilesMatch "^(?!.*\..+)">
    SetHandler php5-script
</FilesMatch>
```